# Switching from two column class to one column

Tags: ieeetran, ieeeconf

I need  to switch from this 2 column style to one column.

My latex script for 2 column style is.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
% *** GRAPHICS RELATED PACKAGES ***
%
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
  \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
  % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
  \graphicspath{{fig/}}
  % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
  % every instance of \includegraphics
  % \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png, .bmp}
\else
  % or other class option (dvipsone, dvipdf, if not using dvips). graphicx
  % will default to the driver specified in the system graphics.cfg if no
  % driver is specified.
   \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
  % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
   \graphicspath{{eps/}}
  % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
  % every instance of \includegraphics
   \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
\fi
\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{flafter}
%\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
%\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
\DontPrintSemicolon

%\usepackage{algorithm2e}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
%\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}



% This allows align equations to be broken across pages
\allowdisplaybreaks
% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

%\doublespacing
\begin{document}

\title{My Title}  

% author names and affiliations
% use a multiple column layout for up to two different
% affiliations

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{}
\IEEEauthorblockA{My name\\
}
}


% use for special paper notices
%\IEEEspecialpapernotice{(Invited Paper)}

% make the title area
\maketitle

\input{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
xxx
\end{IEEEkeywords}


% For peer review papers, you can put extra information on the cover
% page as needed:
% \ifCLASSOPTIONpeerreview
% \begin{center} \bfseries EDICS Category: 3-BBND \end{center}
% \fi
%
% For peerreview papers, this IEEEtran command inserts a page break and
% creates the second title. It will be ignored for other modes.
%\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\input{introduction}
\input{relwork}
\input{analysis}
\input{architecture}
%\input{algorithm}
\input{experiments}
\input{conclusion}


%\section*{Acknowledgments}




\balance
\begin{spacing}{0.88}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{cloud}
\end{spacing}

% that's all folks
\end{document}
```

Comment: make your mwe compilable. we haven't your files. replace them with dummy text (lipsum) and make your code shorter.

Comment: is `\documentclass[conference, onecolumn]{IEEEtran}` what you looking for?

Comment: @Zarko Unless he is very new to LaTeX, I don't think this is what he wants. Even switching using `\onecolumn` will not work in his case because such command would usually leave a lot of space or sometimes starts a new page. I think the OP wants write a large equation that will not fit in just one of the two columns. In such case, he should use `strip` environment after loading `cuted` package.

Comment: You can put equations into a figure* or table*, just don't add a caption.  Of course, they can only go at the top of a page.

Comment: `\documentclass[conference, onecolumn]{IEEEtran}` works

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comments